# How to put many RecyclerView into one RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to build an android app that will receive a lists of genres and movies from api.
I want to make RecyclerView that will contains X amount of RecyclerViews according to the size of genre list.
The genre list can changed from call to call, because more genres can be added on backend ,so i want to create a RecyclerViews programmatically.
I have already created a main recycler view that will contains genres recycler views.
To the adapter i sent list of genres.
In main recycler view item a create another recycler view that will contain movies from this genres.
But here i stoped =]] Don't know how to continue from here to fill the recycler view.
Any suggestions ?

```
genres = new ArrayList<>();
        genres.add(new Genre(0, "Action"));
        genres.add(new Genre(1, "Drama"));

        movies = new ArrayList<>();
        movies.add(new Movie("Titanic", "Test movie titanic", 0));
        movies.add(new Movie("Titanic", "Test movie titanic", 1));
```

Adapter of the main recyclerview:

```
public class MainRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainRVAdapter.MainViewHolder> {

    private List<Genre> genres;

    public MainRVAdapter(List<Genre> genres) {
        this.genres = genres;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_recycler_view_item, parent, false);
        return new MainViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return genres.size();
    }

    public class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private RecyclerView mainRecyclerView;

        public MainViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mainRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainRecyclerView);
        }
    }

}
```

MainRecyclerView implementation;

```
private void initMainRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView mainRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.mainRecyclerView);
        MainRVAdapter adapter = new MainRVAdapter(genres);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        mainRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mainRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i've seen this with many recycler views in a viewpager, it used nested scrolling, could also work with a recycler view as parent. you will need two adapters, one for the outer rv, one for the inner rv, each inner rv gets an own instance of the inner adapter. hope that helps.

Comment: I like the second way , implementation of 2 recyclerview , outer and inner, can you explain a little more how to do that according to the code that i share in question?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a long list of recyclerviews with all genres and movies or do you want a list of genres and when you click on one then you open a list of all movies? Depending on this you will have to either inflate the nested recycler into the main recycler or you have to start a new activity/fragment with the movies recycler.

In both cases you need to define a new adapter:

```
RecyclerView nestedRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.mainRecyclerView);
        NestedRVAdapter adapter = new NestedRVAdapter(movies);
```

With your current data you would need to filter the movies with the wanted genre-id. Would be easier to actually hold the movies of a genre inside the Genre object, maybe as an `ArrayList<Movie>()`.

And genres could be a `HashMap<int, Genre>()`, so you can access them directly:

```
genres.get(1).name

genres.get(1).movies
```

so you could initialize the adapter like this where you create the inner RV:

```
new NestedRVAdapter(genres.get(position).movies)
```

Looks like you have/want to learn, so will leave the details to you. :)

If you are new to the android world and there is nobody forcing you to use java, please consider using kotlin, you will love it! Android Studio has for example a converter to switch your classes from java to kotlin.